# Where did Aquinas say that the "greatest penalty of sin is the loss of the sense of sin"?

Tags: sin, reference-request, thomas-aquinas

Can someone point to me where St. Thomas Aquinas said that the, "greatest penalty of sin is the loss of the sense of sin"?

I heard this from [Catholic Answers Live](http://www.catholic.com//) last week.

Comment: Their [radio calendar is here](http://www.catholic.com/radio/calendar). Could you update the link with the URL of the specific episode you are referring to?

Comment: I totally cannot recall. I have been binge-listening. Perhaps we could ask Patrick Coffin himself if he comes to this forum with his team. :) Thanks for the answer though, @Geremia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

St. Thomas says in

1. [*Super Sent.*, lib. 2 d. 19 q. 1 a. 2 s.c. 2](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/snp2016.html#5148)
2. [*Super Sent.*, lib. 4 d. 20 q. 1 a. 1 qc. 3 arg. 3](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/snp4020.html#18158)
3. [*Super Sent.*, lib. 4 d. 44 q. 3 a. 1 qc. 2 arg. 3](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/snp4043.html#21550)

that "**death is the greatest of punishments**" ("*mors est maxima poenarum*").

Also, he writes in [*Summa Theologiae* II-II, q. 79 a. 4](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS079.html#SSQ79A4THEP1) arg. 4:

> …**the pain of loss** which consists in being deprived of seeing God and is inflicted for the sin of omission, **is a greater punishment than the pain of sense**, which is inflicted for the sin of transgression…

Maybe what they meant is that [sin can be the punishment of sin](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS087.html#FSQ87A2THEP1) or that [ignorance (a defect of the intellect), malice (a defect of the will), weakness, and concupiscence are effects of sin](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FS/FS085.html#FSQ85A3THEP1).

Answer (score 1):

The Summa Theologiae and in the third book of the Summa "Contra Gentiles"

CAtholic answers (I did not hear the program) may have been paraphrasing the concept of Aquinas's view of original justice and the effect it has on our inability to recognize sin.

Comment: Could you link some evidence? Would help.

Comment: Please provide specific references. St. Thomas's [_Opera Omnia_ is online](http://dhspriory.org/thomas/), and [_Roberto Busa, S.J._ is a good concordance of all his works in Latin](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/it/index.age).